# How to parse validation result details from AWS DMS in PHP

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services, dms

In AWS Data Migration service, you can turn on validation. This will create a table on your target server called awsdms_validation_failures_v1 (in the awsdms_control database). This table will be populated with each validation failure that occurs. In this table, there is a `DETAILS` field, that is supposed to be JSON. However, I am not able to parse this JSON, because it seems to be invalid.

Example:

```
[[{'timestamp': '2018-10-28 01:00:01.000000'}, {'timestamp': '2018-10-28 00:00:01.000000'}],]
```

Is this a AWS bug? How can I parse these results in PHP? (For example, I want to get the column name, in this case `timestamp`)

Comment: Not sure how they could pretend that was JSON. The single quotes would need to be double quotes, and the last `,` needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by manually fixing the broken JSON with str_replace statements, to replace the single quotes with double quotes, and remove the last comma.

```
$s = str_replace('\'', '"', $s);

$pos = strrpos($s, ',');
if ($pos !== false) {
    $s = substr_replace($s, '', $pos, 1);
}
```